# MutationObserver doesn't show mutation records after the first non-applicable item to a form input?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am developing an android plugin that checks a list of coupons against cart of sites like Myntra and Jabong. I am new to JavaScript and have managed to write a working code for [Myntra.com](http://www.myntra.com) cart which lists the coupons applicable to the current cart. I am using the MutationObserver to listen to the changes made in the user's cart on submitting coupon from the available list. Following is the JS code:

```
let coupons = ["MYNTRANEW300", "MYNTRANEW1000", "MYNTRANEW600",
    "SKECH1000", "SKECH2500", "DESIFUSION20",
    "SPECIALBIG20", "VEROMODA10"];

let
    applyCoupon = document.getElementsByClassName('apply-coupon');

applyCoupon[0].click();


var discountCoup = [];

function getAmt(x) {
    return x.replace(/\D/g, '');
}


function goOn(modalId) {
    let
        input = modalId.getElementsByClassName('enter-coupon m-textbox')[0],
        submit = modalId.getElementsByClassName('btn primary-btn btn-apply m-button c-white clickable')[0],
        observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, inst) => {
            mutations.forEach(item => {
                if(item.type == 'childList' && item.target.className == 'cart-section' && item.addedNodes.length == 6) {
                    for(let i=0; i<item.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                        if(item.addedNodes[i].className == 'bagContainer cart-page') {
                            let ele = item.addedNodes[i];
                            let appliedCoupon = ele.getElementsByClassName('delete-coupon hint--bottom')[0].getAttribute('data-coupon'),
                                discount = ele.getElementsByClassName('coupon')[0].innerText;
                            console.log(appliedCoupon, discount);
                            discountCoup.push({
                                coupon:appliedCoupon, 
                                offerDiscount:getAmt(discount)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });

    observer.observe(document, {
        'childList': true,
        'subtree': true,
        'characterData':true,
        'attributes': true
    });

    coupons.forEach(function (item, idx) {
        input.value = item;
        submit.click();
    });
}

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, inst) => {
    var modal = document.getElementById('lb-apply-coupon');
    if (modal) {
        goOn(modal);
        inst.disconnect();
        return;
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
});
```

However, I wrote a similar code for [www.jabong.com](http://www.jabong.com) but the MutationObserver doesn't record any mutations after the first non-applicable coupon is passed to the input.

```
let coupons = ["FORMAL15", "CUPOJAB25", "EXTRA10", "BEST20", "AC1000", "SDBG150", "SDBG200", "FCSD100", 
"MTM2500", "SHOWTIME20", "APPLE500", "LEECO1500", 
"LAPTOP1500", "GD17MAY75", "GD17MAY150"];

let
    applyCoupon = document.getElementsByClassName('have-a-coupon text-uppercase');

applyCoupon[0].click();


var discountCoup = [];
function getAmt(x) {
    return x.replace(/\D/g, '');
}

function goOn(input, submit) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, inst) => {
            mutations.forEach(item => {
                if(item.type == 'childList' && item.target.className == 'client-prod' && item.addedNodes.length == 3) {
                    for(let i=0; i<item.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                        if(item.addedNodes[i].className == 'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 cart-summery-wrapper') {
                            let ele = item.addedNodes[i];
                            let appliedCoupon = ele.getElementsByClassName('remove-coupon text-center text-uppercase')[0].getAttribute('data-coupon'),
                                discount = ele.getElementsByClassName('right green-txt')[0].innerText;
                            console.log(appliedCoupon, discount);
                            discountCoup.push({
                                coupon:appliedCoupon, 
                                offerDiscount:getAmt(discount)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });

    observer.observe(document, {
        'childList': true,
        'subtree': true,
        'characterData':true,
        'attributes': true
    });

    coupons.forEach(function (item, idx) {
        console.log(item, idx);
        input.value = item;
        try {
             submit.click();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, inst) => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
        if(mutation.type == 'childList' 
            && mutation.target.className == 'modal-dialog modal-md' 
                && mutation.addedNodes.length == 1) {
                    let modal = mutation.addedNodes[0],
                        input = modal.getElementsByClassName('form-group text-input input-group')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
                        submit = modal.getElementsByClassName('input-group-addon jbApplyCoupon')[0];
                        console.log(modal);
                        goOn(input, submit);
                        inst.disconnect();
                        return;
                }
    });

    // var modal = document.getElementById('apply-voucher-modal');
    // if (modal) {
    //     goOn(modal);
    //     inst.disconnect();
    //     return;
    // }
});

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
});
```

I am confused and after all the things I tried, I am here to ask for help.

PS: This is my first question in the community.Likewise my first ever encounter with Javascript.

Comment: `submit` usually reloads the page or, in case of AJAX-site, a portion of the page, so you'll have to re-register MutationObserver.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: I used a console in Chrome to manually check whether MutationObserver listened to DOM changes even after the submit button was clicked. The test was positive. So the issue is not related to submit button. However, the DOm changes are not detected after the first encounter of a non-applicable coupon.
I used a simple observer and sequential inputs and clicks via JS. All changes were notified. But when using it in the loop, the problem persists.